# Xcode private keys for development and distribution

Tags: xcode, provisioning

I know this question is a partial repetition of some other similar questions I found on SOF but I didn't find an exact conclusive answer to this.

I can create development build on my Xcode but not distribution builds. It shows "Valid signing identity not found" for my distribution provisioning profile in Xcode's organizer
. In Keychain -> (login) Certificates, it shows reveal contents triangle for Developer Certificate but not for Distribution Certificate. I downloaded the distribution certificate again but it didn't help.

What is the problem here? I was under the impression that if I have the private key, it should work for both Certificates. Is this assumption wrong? What do I need to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How did you create Distr. certificate, automatically with Xcode or manually? I can't manage how to create Dist. cert. and profile with Xcode as apple suggesting. So I ended up with two private keys in Keychain, one for each certificate type. And create and downloaded distribution certificate manually from provisioning portal.